# Why does A ∪ (B ∩ C) = (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If I have the elements from sets A and B, and I want to find the set A ∪ (B ∩ C), I end up with just the elements of A. On the other hand, if I have the elements from A and B and want to find (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C), it seems like I end up with (A ∩ B) ∩ A, which is just (A ∩ B). This set was not a possible outcome with A ∪ (B ∩ C).

Where has my reasoning going wrong?

Comment: How are you getting that $A \cup (B \cap C) = A$? I believe the only case where this is true is when $(B \cap C) \subseteq A$.

Comment: It is possible that $A\cap B = A$ (*occurs when $A\subseteq B$*) so what you've written doesn't preclude anything.  It is unclear exactly what was going through your mind when you were writing this.  Try working it out with specific sets:  For example $A=\{1,2,3\}, B=\{3,4,5\}, C=\{1,3,5\}$.  One should have $A\cup (B\cap C)=\{1,2,3\}\cup (\{3,4,5\}\cap \{1,3,5\}) = \{1,2,3\}\cup \{3,5\}=\{1,2,3,5\}$.  Similarly for the other side (*left for you to verify*).  See [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_Distributes_over_Intersection) for more details and a proof of the identity.

Comment: Let's think this out.  You take elements of $A \cup (B \cap C)$ and end up with elements of $A$ and you don't think that is right.  Let's *try* to take an element in $A \cup (B \cap C)$ that *isn't* in $A$.  Is that possible.  $A \cup (B\cap C)$ are the elements of $A$ (we don't want those) and the elements of $B \cap C$.  Okay, let's take an element of $B \cap C$ that isn't in $A$. Let A be GIRLS, B be MAMMALS, C be VEGITARIANS.  We need a vegitarian mammal that is a boy.  Possible?  Of course.  $A \cup (B \cap C)$ are all the girls as well as the vegitarian mammals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $B \cap C \subseteq B$ and $B \cap C \subseteq C$, we have
$$A \cup (B \cap C) \subseteq A \cup B$$
and
$$A \cup (B \cap C) \subseteq A \cup C$$
This shows that $A \cup (B \cap C)$ is contained in both $A \cup B$ and $A \cup C$, so it is contained in their intersection:
$$A \cup (B \cap C)\subseteq (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$$
This proves containment in one direction.

For the opposite direction, suppose that $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$. There are two possibilities: either $x \in A$ or $x \not\in A$.

If $x \in A$ then certainly $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$.

On the other hand, if $x \not\in A$, then $x$ must be in both $B$ and $C$, since $x \in (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup C)$. Consequently, $x \in B \cap C$, and therefore $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$.

In both cases we have $x \in A \cup (B \cap C)$. This proves the containment
$$(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) \subseteq A \cup (B \cap C)$$
so we're done.

Answer (score 1):

A ∪ (B ∩ C) means $ x : x \in A  $  or  $ x \in B,C $ or $ x \in A,B,C $

(A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C) means $ x: x \in A $ or $ x \in B $ or $ x \in A,B $ and $ x \in A $ or $ x \in C $ or $ x \in A,C $ => look at this statement and see the possible combinations => $ x : x \in A  $ or $  x \in B,C $ or $ x \in A,B,C $.

Comment: Why is x ∈ (A ∩ C) not an option for the set (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C)? If x ∈ A,C, then (A ∪ B) is true because x ∈ A, and (A ∪ C) is true because x ∈  (A ∩ C). Thus the set (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C) becomes A ∩ (A ∩ C), which is just (A ∩ C). I feel like I'm thinking about this incorrectly but I don't know what rule or system of thought I'm breaking.

Comment: I suppose if x ∈ (A ∩ C) then x ∈ A, which is an option given by A ∪ (B ∩ C), so I have not discovered a location in (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C) that does not hold for A ∪ (B ∩ C) as well. However, it feels significant that I can say x ∈ (A ∩ C) when looking at (A ∪ B) ∩ (A ∪ C), but not when looking at A ∪ (B ∩ C), yet these are supposed to be equivalent forms of the same logic. Shouldn't the exact same information be available from both versions if they are just different ways of writing the same thing? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: @IgnorantCuriosity Rather, what is your motivation for trying to use $A\cap C$?  Let us examine an example of: $~A=\{1, 2\}, B=\{2,3\}, C= \{3, 4\}~$. Now we have:$$\begin{align}A\cup (B\cap C) ~=~& \{1,2\}\cup\{3\}&~=~&\{1,2,3\} \\[1ex] (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)~=~& \{1,2,3\}\cap\{1,2,3,4\}&~=~&\{1,2,3\}\end{align}$$  However, $A\cap C=\{\}$ and what help does this provide in examining the equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

> If I have the elements from sets A and B, and I want to find the set A ∪ (B ∩ C), I end up with just the elements of A.

Not generally, and more importantly: not relevant.

$\cup$ means union: $A\cup B$ is set of elements in either set A *or* set B.

$\cap$ means intersection: $B\cap C$ is set of elements in both set B *and* set C.

---

$A\cup(B\cap C) \subseteq (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$   If you have an element either from set A *or* from both sets B and C,  then you have elements which are from both either sets A or B *and* from either sets A or C.

- Can you show that this is so?   Hint: Use case work: (If an element is from set A then..., and if an element is from both B and C, then ...., therefore ....)

$A\cup(B\cap C) \supseteq (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$   If you have elements which are from both either sets A or B *and* from either sets A or C, then you have elements which are either from set A *or* from sets B and C.

- Can you show this too?

Answer (score 1):

Let's think it out slowly.

Let $x \in A \cup B\cap C$.  Then either Case 1: $x \in A$ or Case 2: $x \in B \cap C$.  (or case 3: both).

Case 1: $x \in A$.

So $x \in A \cup B$.  And $x \in A \cup C$.  So $x \in (A\cup B) \cap (A \cup B)$.

Case 2: $x \in B \cap C$.

So $x \in B$.  So $x \in A \cup B$.

But $x \in C$ also.  So $x \in A \cup C$.

So $x \in (A\cup B)\cap (A \cup C)$.

So whether $x \in A$ or $x \in B \cap C$, $x \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$ so $A \subseteq (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

....

Let $y \in (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$.

Either $y \in A$ or $y \not \in A$.

If $y \in A$ then $y \in A \cup (A \cap B)$.

If $y \not \in A$...

then $y \in A \cup B$ so $y \in A$ *OR* $y \in B$. If $y \not \in A$ then $y \in B$.

likewise $y \in A \cup C$.  If $y \not \in A$ then $y \in C$so $y \in B$ and $y \in C$.

So $y \in B \cap C$.  So $y \in A \cup (B \cap C)$.

So no matter how $y \in (A\cup B) \cap (A\cup C)$ it follows $y \in A \cup (B \cap C)$

So $(A \cup B) \cap (A\cup C) \subseteq  A \cup (B \cap C)$

And $A \cup (B \cap C) \subseteq (A \cup B) \cap (A\cup C)$

So $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A\cup C)$